# Gradle.properties not passed through to my Java application

Tags: java, gradle

**Issue**

I have a project-level `gradle.properties` file that defines various `systemProp.*` values (especially proxy stuff). I got this idea from [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties).

I'm expecting those properties to be passed through to the JVM that runs my application, so that my application can use those values at runtime.

However, it looks like none of those `systemProp` values are passed through.

Am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work?

**Repeatable Example**

I created a small GitHub repo that shows this in action: https://github.com/gmacster/gradle-system-properties-passthrough

I have a custom `systemProp` defined in `gradle.properties` called `some-sample-prop`. My `main()` method reads the value of this property and logs it.

I'm just running `gradlew run` with no extra args.

**Version Info**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          11.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.2+9-LTS)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system properties defined in `gradle.properties` are only passed to the JVM that is running Gradle itself, not the JVMs that are forked by what ever plugin you're using to run your application. So in order to pass the system properties from Gradle to the application that is started by Gradle, you need to manually copy them to the `systemProperties` property of the `JavaExec` task. Assuming you're using the `run` task provided by the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), and you have a `systemProp.proxy.host=example.proxy.host.com` in your `gradle.properties` file, you would need to do this (see also [this very old answer](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-should-i-be-handling-passing-system-properties-from-gradle-to-my-tests/7171) in the Gradle forums):

```
task.named('run') {
    systemProperties = [
        'proxy.host': System.getProperty('proxy.host')
    ]
}
```

But let me ask you why you need this indirection. I assume you only need those properties for running the application. If this is the case it would be easier to define them directly in the build script:

```
task.named('run') {
    systemProperties = [
        'proxy.host': 'example.proxy.host.com'
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The reason for the indirection: I would like the proxy to be defined for both Gradle itself (for downloading dependencies from behind a corporate firewall) and for the running application (for connecting to resources hosted beyond that corporate firewall). I had hoped I could just define them once and be done with it.

I'll move forward with the manual propagation of the proxy settings I need, and call it good.

Answer (score -1):

you can access even though it is not a good idea as this file it is supposed to store properties to be used for gradle tasks only.

I suggest you to have a application.properties under *src/main/resources* and read the file from there.

But, if you want to store in the gradle.properties, here is how you can retrieve it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("gradle.properties");

    // load a properties file
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);

    System.out.println(prop.getProperty("systemProp.some-sample-prop"));
}
```

It will print:

```
hello world
```

Comment: As far as I understand the application read the properties using `System.getProperty(String)`. It does not know about the `gradle.properties` file. Once the application gets deployed somewhere the `gradle.properties` file will not be available, so I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: @britter Unless he adds this file into resources in the gradle script. But my suggestion was to add this properties in the application properties under /src/main/resources. I was just trying to show a way to get frm that file or any file if that is wat he really need.